# The LayoutBuilder always reset the field widget. Is there a widget instead of LayoutBuilder that maintains an input value?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layoutbuilder

When the screen is resized and LayoutBuilder runs, the value entered is always reset. Even if the same widget variables are used, this differs from Wrap widgets.
So is there any widget that still maintains the entered values? (don't want to use the controller for each field)

[video example.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/assets/59549741/f082c635-86db-4650-80fb-dfb53b73f623)
code example: (you can test this code on this [website](https://dartpad.dev/))

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Form Styling Demo';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(appTitle),
        ),
        body: const MyCustomForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomForm extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCustomForm({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build');
    String bValue = '';
    const bTitle = Text('b field');
    final bField = SizedBox(
      width: 200,
      child: TextFormField(
        initialValue: bValue,
        onChanged: (text) {
          bValue = text;
        },
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Enter your username',
        ),
      ),
    );
    final bButton = TextButton(
      onPressed: () => print(bValue),
      child: Text('bValue = $bValue'),
    );
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              return constraints.maxWidth < 200
                  ? Column(
                      children: [
                        aTitle,
                        aField,
                        aButton,
                      ],
                    )
                  : Row(
                      children: [
                        aTitle,
                        Flexible(child: aField),
                        aButton,
                      ],
                    );
            },
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 50),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
          child: Wrap(
            alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
            children: [
              bTitle,
              bField,
              bButton,
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

//tried to move all parameters out of the `Build`
String aValue = '';
const aTitle = Text('a field');
final aField = SizedBox(
  width: 200,
  child: TextFormField(
    key: Key('1'), //tried to add Key
    initialValue: aValue,
    onChanged: (text) {
      aValue = text;
    },
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
      labelText: 'Enter your username',
    ),
  ),
);
final aButton = TextButton(
  onPressed: () => print('aValue = $aValue'),
  child: Text('print bValue'),
);
```

In this video, you can see this issue at `aField`. The input in the `aField` disappeared after the layout was changed(that should not disappear and the aValue still not reset). The input in the `bField` is still alive after the layout was changed. But the `bField` is in the `Wrap` widget which is not useful like the `LayoutBuilder` widget.

Comment: Does it reproduce the same issue on local device(web build)?

Comment: I tested it on my computer with Flutter Web and It can reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving Value key to TextFormField

Comment: I tried adding the key for aField and this is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is doing this:

```
String bValue = '';
```

and

```
child: TextFormField(
    initialValue: bValue,
```

in your `build()` method.  This will reinitialize `bValue` to an empty string on each build. You should be prepared for build to be called 60 times per second.  If a value needs to persist between builds (which this does), you need to move it out into State.  Typically, this is done with a `TextEditingController`.  I believe there are Flutter codelabs on flutter.dev to demonstrate this.

Comment: Correct, I generally solve this kind of errors by using ValueKey, but at first I never saw that he is setting value in build method 

Comment: Hi, I think this isn't setState so the build will not reinitialize any parameter. However, I tried to move aValue, aTitle, and aField but this aField still refreshes when ```constraints.maxWidth < 200```.

Comment: @s4nk37 Can you give me a code that you fixed from my `code example:`? I am still stuck with this.

Comment: build() will be called even when you don't call setState.  *You* do not control builds... the framework does.  *You* need to imagine build() is always being executed 60 times per second.  In practice, most of those are not called.

Comment: Thank you for your new knowledge. I tried to move out all parameters in `Build` and added the key but it still not working. Any way to fix that?

Comment: SO is not a good forum for incremental code advice.  I suggest you join the Flutter Discord and interact there.  The link is in flutter.dev/community

Comment: Thank you. I wonder something if I pass `aValue` and `bValue` in the `build` and the `build` always resets this value to initial(empty string). Why when we print this value, does the value still display the last input?
I updated my code and video, you can see this.

Comment: Because the TextFormField is rebuilding locally.  What you aren't safe from is the outer widget rebuilding, and that's what you must fix.